# Swift error - Use of instance member on type

Tags: swift, methods, struct

Following code gives me error: "Use of instance member 'getRandomBoy' on type Snips...".

I would like to use the method 'getRandomBoy' inside of the 'snipArray'.

Is this possible?

```
Import Darwin

struct Snips {

let boyNames: [String]

let snipArray: [String] = [
    "Drink A beer",
    "Drink yet another Beer",
    "Drink 4 beers",
    "\(getRandomBoy()) has to drink)"
    ]

func getRandomSnip() -> String{
    let randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(snipArray.count)))
    return snipArray[randomNumber]
}

func getRandomBoy() -> String{
    let randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(boyNames.count)))
    return boyNames[randomNumber]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `static` keyword before `function` and `variables` declaration to access inside methods.

Here is the modified code of yours':

```
struct Snips {

    static let boyNames = ["Hi", "Hello"]

    static let snipArray: [String] = [
        "Drink A beer",
        "Drink yet another Beer",
        "Drink 4 beers",
        "\(Snips.getRandomBoy()) has to drink)"
    ]

    static func getRandomSnip() -> String{
        let randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(snipArray.count)))
        return snipArray[randomNumber]
    }

    static func getRandomBoy() -> String{
        let randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(boyNames.count)))
        return boyNames[randomNumber]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!